# Highlight whole block when mouse hovers on it in css

Tags: css, jsp

Here I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjgwb/) to show what I have currently. In this when mouse hovers on link it highlights only part not the whole block. We can still see the black color on top and bottom. I want to highlight whole block when mouse hovers on it. How can I do it in CSS?

Also I'm declaring this in header.jsp [common to all] and include it in all other files. So how can I keep the link highlighted when user is on that page?

Answer (score 1):

a few small modifications:

remove `height` from `#navbar`

remove `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` from `#navBar ul li`

add `line-height: 42px;` to `#navBar ul li a`

That's it! :)

```
#navBar {
    float: right;
    background:#000;
    /* removed height here */
}
#navBar ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    /* removed padding-top and padding-bottom here */
}
#navBar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 42px;     /* added */
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/YfQgZ/

Answer (score 0):

look at the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjgwb/2/

i modified it a bit. Now the hover should work correct and if you want the item to stay selected, you have to add the `selected` class to the correspondend `li` tag

**edit**: now with example for `selected`

Comment: How can change li class dynamically? Because this div is common in all pages?